# How to resolve - Provider org.slf4j.simple.SimpleServiceProvider not a subtype?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, slf4j

I changed dependency version for slf4j.simple from 1.6.0 to 2.0.0alpha1 and facing this error on running mvn clean install command -

```
<dependency>     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>     <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>     <version>2.0.0-alpha1</version>     <scope>provided</scope> </dependency>
```

Stack trace -

```
Error during instantiation of the implementation object
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.slf4j.spi.SLF4JServiceProvider: Provider org.slf4j.simple.SimpleServiceProvider not a subtype
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.findServiceProviders(LoggerFactory.java:104)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:147)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:139)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getProvider(LoggerFactory.java:418)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:404)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:353)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:379)
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this error was caused by SLF4J 2.0 searching for instances of `org.slf4j.spi.SLF4JServiceProvider` in the ThreadContextClassLoader, which was set to the Application classloader by default. Unfortunately, my code was actually running inside a *completely separate* classloader which contained its own instances of `slf4j-api` and `slf4j-simple`.

The bottom line is that `slf4j-api` inside my isolated classloader found `slf4j-simple` inside the Application classloader, which was not assignable (i.e. "not a subtype") to the service interface.

I was able to fix the problem by setting the ThreadContextClassLoader correctly before my code executed `LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz)`.

Personally though, I think this is a bug in how SLF4J is using `ServiceLoader`. Specifically, `LoggerFactory.findServiceProviders()` should be using:

```java
ServiceLoader.load(SLF4JServiceProvider.class, LoggerFactory.class.getClassLoader())
```

instead of

```java
ServiceLoader.load(SLF4JServiceProvider.class)
```

Comment: FWIW this has now been fixed in SLF4J 2.0.4.